# How to get the value of one column based on the value of other column of same row in case of one to many relation in MySql

Tags: mysql, one-to-many

There are two tables say `t1` and `t2` with one to many relations (`t1` having multiple records in `t2`), below image is `t2`.

[image]

Please help me write MySQL query to fetch all the records of `t1` with join to get `value` where `title` is 'First Name' in `t2`

Note: `my_fr_id` is foreign key (refers to primary key of `t1`)

Hope I'm clear with my query, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the structure of `t1` it's difficult to be exact but this is probably close (it assumes `my_fr_id` is a foreign key to `t1.id`):

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.value 
FROM t1
JOIN t2 ON t2.my_fr_id = t1.id AND t2.title = 'First Name'
```